# My own solution for Kotlin's try-with-resources absence

Tags: kotlin, try-with-resources, autocloseable

Kotlin provides the `use` function for `Closeable` objects, but it seems they forgot to consider `AutoCloseable` (e.g. DB prepared statements) for the try-with-resources full Java equivalent.

I've implemented the next "home-made" solution:

```
inline fun <T:AutoCloseable,R> trywr(closeable: T, block: (T) -> R): R {
    try {
        return block(closeable);
    } finally {
        closeable.close()
    }
}
```

Then you can use it the next way:

```
fun countEvents(sc: EventSearchCriteria?): Long {
    return trywr(connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event")) {
        var rs = it.executeQuery()
        rs.next()
        rs.getLong(1)
    }
}
```

I'm new to Kotlin and I would like to know if I'm missing something important in my own solution that could give me problems/leakages in a production environment.

Comment: the reason they don't support `AutoClosable` out-of-the-box is that they are still to implement Java8 support, as well to support JDK8 classes

Comment: You could always copy the source for `use` and change `Closeable` to `AutoCloseable` (see [ReadWrite.kt:145-177](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/8549ec7645ff6db4d5fede2c43034be66683561a/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/ReadWrite.kt#L145-L177).

Comment: Consider using java 8 for the pattern. You can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43269795/2463695

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your implementation will work fine but it's different from a standard try-with-resources implementation. If you want it to work like in Java you should do something like that:

```
inline fun <T : AutoCloseable, R> trywr(closeable: T, block: (T) -> R): R {
  var currentThrowable: java.lang.Throwable? = null
  try {
    return block(closeable)
  } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
    currentThrowable = throwable as java.lang.Throwable
    throw throwable
  } finally {
    if (currentThrowable != null) {
      try {
        closeable.close()
      } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
        currentThrowable.addSuppressed(throwable)
      }
    } else {
      closeable.close()
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

As [mfulton26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260556/36260918?noredirect=1#comment60157138_36260918) `kotlin.Throwable` doesn't contain `addSuppressed(Throwable)` method so we have to cast `kotlin.Throwable` to `java.lang.Throwable` to make the code work.

Comment: There is no `addSuppress(Throwable)` method on `kotlin.Throwable` and you cannot use `java.lang.Throwable` in a Kotlin try-catch so how does this code compile (other than `s/throwble/throwable/`)?

Comment: @mfulton26 I believe its supposed to be `Exception` instead of `Throwable`.

Comment: @mfulton26 Thanks, that's a good point. Updated the code to make it compile.

Answer (score 2):

Since Kotlin 1.1, `.use`  has an `AutoCloseable` implementation.

```
@SinceKotlin("1.1")
@Suppress("INVISIBLE_REFERENCE", "INVISIBLE_MEMBER")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T : AutoCloseable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    var exception: Throwable? = null
    try {
        return block(this)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        exception = e
        throw e
    } finally {
        this.closeFinally(exception)
    }
}
```

Copied from [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/jre7/src/kotlin/AutoCloseable.kt#L33)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [`use()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) as defined on `Closable`.